# Why am I getting espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll to' on view 'with id?

Tags: android, android-espresso

Why am I getting error the following error in my Espresso test:

> android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll to' on view 'with id: com.espresso:id/locate_car_button'.

Here is the code of the button I'm testing:

```
public static void clickButtonWithId(@IdRes int id) {
  onView(withId(id)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(scrollTo()).perform(click());
}
```

Comment: What are you using your 'scroll to' in, is it a ListView or a RecyclerView? Read here about RecyclerView: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/lists

Comment: its a button, to make sure its visible. If I remove it I get the error: espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 539, 928 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id: com.espresso:id/locate_car_button'.

Comment: Where does the button reside, what is it's parent view?

Comment: It's inside a constraintlayout which it's included inside a fragment

Comment: The button is inside a fragment? What is the fragment container? I am asking about the parent layout of the button. There is a quick trick of using the [Espresso Test Recorder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRkDVvB106k) in Android Studio to mimic the behaviour on an app and get an espresso test generated from it. This will give you a rough idea of what's different in your test and the one recorded. You might even go ahead and use the test recorder instead if it suits you.

Comment: You can also try using something as; 
`onView(withId(R.id.locate_car_button)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));` for visibility and for click add,
 `onView(withId(R.id.locate_car_button)).perform(click());`

Comment: Didn't work similar error: single click - At Coordinates: 719, 1238 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id: com.espresso:id/locate_car_button'

Comment: Include your layout file and complete test in the question.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. i discovered that if I stop debugger in the onView line and I scroll manually the device till the element to click, then it works perfectly. So I am still investigating why it does not work automatically.
May be this helps someone.